# MySQL - Selecting common value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a query but I don't know how.

I have three tables: `chat`, `chat_user` and `user`

Something like:

```
 ---------      ------------------------       ------------------
|  chat   |    |        chat_user       |     |       user       |
 ---------      ------------------------       ------------------
| id |  1 |    | id | chat_id | user_id |     | id | external_id | 
 ---- ----      ---- --------- ---------       ---- -------------
               | 1  |    1    |    1    |     |  1 |     111     |
               | 2  |    1    |    2    |     |  2 |     222     |
                ---- --------- ---------       ---- -------------
```

I need to select one chat.id FOR TWO `user`s. In the example above, the users 111 and 222 are sharing the `chat.id` 1. What I need is to get as a select result the `chat.id` 1 (as the example above) only once when searching `external_id` 111 and 222.

I found some answer here but they didn't help a lot... I always get other chat.id values.

If you need any extra explanation, I'm right here to answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read your question before you post it next time.

Comment: @edwardmp In fact, I had already especified that I needed to select one chat.id for TWO users. I just added some code markups... Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually an example of a "set-within-sets" query:  you are asking about whether the set of users for a given chat contain certain users.  I like to solve such questions with aggregation and a `having` clause, because this is a very general approach.

Here is the query:

```
select c.*
from chat_user cu join
     user u
     on cu.user_id = u.id join
     chat c
     on cu.chat_id = c.id
group by cu.chat_id
having sum(u.external_id = '111') > 0 and
       sum(u.external_id = '222') > 0
```

This is aggregating by the chat in `chat_user`.  The first condition in the `having` clause says:  "Is user 111 present?".  The second says:  "Is user 222 present?"  Only chat ids with examples of both users are returned.

Comment: In fact I need the table `chat` because I have some more columns that I didn't specified here.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id FROM chat AS c
INNER JOIN chat_user AS cu1 ON c.id = cu1.chat_id
INNER JOIN chat_user AS cu2 ON c.id = cu2.chat_id AND cu1.id < cu2.id
INNER JOIN user AS u1 ON u1.id = cu1.user_id
INNER JOIN user AS u2 ON u2.id = cu2.user_id
WHERE u1.external_id = 111
AND u2.external_id = 222
```

The `AND cu1.id < cu2.id` part forces the `chat_user` with `id` 1 to be joined es `cu1` and the `chat_user` with `id` 2 to be joined as `cu2`. This eliminates the record where the `chat_user` with `id` 2 is joined as `cu1` and the `chat_user` with `id` 1 is joined as `cu2`. My guess is that you omitted this clause in your attempts and this resulted in duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I need to find a `chat` that have `external_id` 111 and 222 (for the example in the question). I edited the question.

Comment: But the chat table doesn't have a column called external_id ?

Comment: `external_id` is from table `user`

Comment: @CainaSouza In light of your new requirements, I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Oswald! I made a mix of your answer and Gordon Linoff one!